# PHP - Properly validate and/or sanitize form input

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, sanitization

I have a form on a website for visitors to create an account. I need to make sure each field is in a certain format before saving it.

**Username** - only letters, numbers and underscore.

**Password** - Anything that's not harmful, how avoid php/html code?

**Email** - valid email (`filter_var()`?)

**Mobile** - 10 digit number (`is_numeric()`?)

**Birthdate** - needs to be YYYY-MM-DD, I'm using input type 'date'

Do I need to use Reg Ex to accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php

Comment: I already read that, I don't want to sanitize a username. It needs to be a certain format. For example, I couldn't have `ef141%2wetw%2` as a username.

Comment: "Do I need to use Reg Ex to accomplish this?" No, you don't _have_ to, but it would probably be the most efficient way

Comment: better go with regex then

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at
Php Filter / Validation or event Sanitization
http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php